# Is it possible to convert an object's class to another?

Tags: java, class, oop, subclass, superclass

Let's say that we have three classes: Person, Student extends Person, and OfficeWorker extends Person.

```
public class Person{
   //fields and methods, especially constructor & getter-setter methods
   private String occupation;
}
public class Student extends Person{
   private int education;
   //Constructor assigns education zero to a student
   public void dailyEducation(){
      this.education++;
   }
   public void finishEducation(){
      this.education = "Office Worker";
      //_________________________________
   }
}
public Class OfficeWorker extends Person{
   //own fields and methods
}
public class mainF{
   //typical psvm(s[]a)
}
```

So what should I put in either the blank in the Student class or even in the main function in order to change the person (which is a student) into a person that is an OfficeWorker?

Comment: You could make finishEducation return a Person, so in this case you'd return `new OfficeWorker()`. But that won't change the type of the existing object, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach:

```
interface Person {
    String getOccupation();
}

class Student implements Person {

    @Override
    public String getOccupation() {
        return "student";
    }
}

class OfficeWorker implements Person {

    @Override
    public String getOccupation() {
        return "office worker";
    }
}

class LifetimePerson implements Person {
    private Person currentRole = new Student();

    @Override
    public String getOccupation() {
        return currentRole.getOccupation();
    }
    
    public void finishEducation() {
        currentRole = new OfficeWorker();
    }
}
```

But what do we do if `finishEducation()` gets called again once you've become an office worker? Do we throw an exception, or ignore it?

Whether this is a useful approach depends on the details of your requirements.